# $M=\lbrace 4n: n\in\Bbb Z \rbrace$ is a maximal ideal of ring of even integers

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

To prove: $M=(4)=\lbrace 4n: n\in\Bbb Z \rbrace$ is a maximal ideal of ring of even integers $E$.

Proof. Since $2\notin (4)$, we get $(4)\neq E$. Let $J$ be an ideal of $E$ such that $(4)\subset J$, then there exists an element $x\in J$, but $x\notin (4)$. Consequently, $x=4n+2$ for some integer $n$.

Now, $2=x-4n\in J$, (since $J$ is an ideal). That is, every integral being multiple of $2$ is in $J$. Therefore, $E\subseteq J$. So, $J=E$.

I couldn't justify the line "**That is, every integral being multiple of $2$ is in $J$**".

Comment: Perhaps easier: $M$ is a maximal proper additive subgroup of $E$. Easier because we know all subgroups of $E$ (and of $\mathbb Z$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $2$ is in $J$ and $J$ is an ideal , $2 + 2 + \ldots + 2 = 2n \in J$ by closure for every  integer $n$. This means that

> every integral being multiple of 2 is in J

Comment: Is it true that in an Ideal $I$, $x+y\in I$ for all $x, y\in I$?

Comment: If $x \in I$ and $y$ is an element in the ring then $xy \in I$. Please have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)#Definitions_and_motivation)

Comment: Yes, but in this case, the ring $E$ is of even integers, so in general $n\notin E$.

Comment: But by defintion of the ideal $(I, +)$ is a subgroup of the ring, that implies $x,y \in I \implies x+y \in I$, so I wrote $2+2+ \ldots + 2 =2n$